# I cannot install android-sdk on linux(centos)

Tags: android, sdk

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html here it's said 
"If you downloaded a .zip or .tgz package (instead of the SDK installer), unpack it to a safe location on your machine. By default, the SDK files are unpacked into a directory named android-sdk-."
I untar this archive and I'm trying to add a new avd device by running *tools/android*, but it doesn't see any target platform(which means android sdk wasn't installed). Moreover, when I'm trying to set android-sdk target from eclipse to the unpacked folder, it says that it cannot find android-sdk there. So what is the solution? I'm downloading the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you installed is just the AVD Manager, not the SDK itself.

You can install the SDK from the AVD Manager, go to "Available Packages" and expand "Android Repository":

[image]

From there you can choose the SDK version you want, along with samples to install.

I'd recommend installing the "SDK Tools" also.

Just click through the dialogs and accept any license agreements. Once that's installed,you will be able to create a virtual machine and point Eclipse to the SDK.

Comment: I can't get to Android SDK and AVD Manager because it says Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preferences.

Comment: It sounds like your download or installation may be corrupt. I installed CentOS into a VM and the SDK manager installed fine...

Comment: the problem was in older version of java